# Duplicated dates POWER BI

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

I am new in Power BI, and I am struggling with how to resolve an issue.
I made measures to calculate my total feedback. The feedback column can be POS, NEG, and Neutral. The overall sentiment I calculated by taking pos feedback and dividing by all feedback.

```
totalFeedback = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('feeback'),'feedback'[sentiment] = "POS")/ COUNTA('feedback'[sentiment])
```

Now when I want to calculate the difference between two months. Example today's, and last month I get an error saying duplicates dates.

```
difference = CALCULATE([totalFeedback], DATEADD(FILTER('comment'[created_at], 'comment'[created_at] < TODAY()),-1,MONTH)
```

I get an error saying: `A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to function 'DATEADD'. This is not supported`

What I did was I created a DATE TABLE and made a relationship with the comment[created_at].
DimDate= CALENDARAUTO(12).

Now, I don't get the error anymore, but non of the data is shown when adding the measure in the table.
I need advice, thanks